# blackberry and php verification

Tags: php, blackberry, verification

Is there a way to verify a users blackberry pin using php ? or any other methods you may suggest :)

**EDIT**

1. Users visits website: example.com.
2. user signs up enters a blackberry pin.
3. php/javascript/blackberry web Works generates a 4 digit code and sends it to blackberry pin (messenger).
4. reads the 4 digit code returns to example.com and enters the 4 digit code into the website 5. click continue
5. tell user that they have successfully verified the pin

Comment: why not use regex ? then send them with sms ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

php is server side code that would not execute on a blackberry.  php could verify a pin assuming that there was some client side (on the blackberry device) code executing that would pass this information to php.

I found this forum thread discussing how to do this in java: 
http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Get-the-pin-number-of-a-Blackberry-Device/td-p/223412

Comment: I would be happy to just send them a message on their bbm and say ur verification code is 1234 enter this on the website

Comment: You need to provide more context, I have no idea what you are asking here.

Comment: I want to verify a bbpin. So when they sign up on my website, they should receive a message on their blackberry messenger with a code to confirm their code which then can be entered on the website

Comment: sending an sms verifies a users simcard not their blackberry pin if that makes sense. I am more than happy to create the code generate everything i just need to pass them a message one time only to send a verification code just like you would with emails on sign ups and then they click a link but in my case a 4 digit code can be send to a blackberry messenger so they can put that to verify that the blackberry pin belongs to them.

Comment: I do not understand this 4 digit code to verify the blackberry pin.  I understand blackberry's have a pin associated with them.  Regardless, I still do not understand what you want to do.  Can you please explain in logical order what you want or how you see this working.

Comment: `1.` Users visits website: example.com. `2.` user signs up enters a blackberry pin. `3.` php generates a 4 digit code and sends it to blackberry pin (messenger).`4.` reads the 4 digit code returns to example.com and enters the 4 digit code into the website `5.` click continue `6.` tell user that they have successfully verified the pin

Comment: @Val: I think the problem with that is 3.  I am not sure php can send a message to blackberry messenger by itself.  It would need some help sending this message just like php would need help sending an SMS text message.  (This is the same as how php when it sends an email usually falls back on sendmail unless you configure it otherwise.

Comment: I was checking around the `webworks` api it has something about messages and sms but not the bbm and they use javascript and java. to manipulate that action thats what i need `3.` :) everything else i can handle it :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any way to send a BBM message from a webserver. Once RIM re-releases the BBM API you could possably dedicate a Blackberry to pull account verification codes and PINs from your server and use an application on the device to send out the BBM message. That seems a little in-elegant. There may be a JavaScript method that can get the PIN for you, but I'm not very familiar with JavaScript.

Another way would be to implement the Blackberry Push API into your application, but this may be more overhead than is reasonable for your application.

The way I would do it is write a small Blackberry app that can be installed over the air from your website. The app could gather the user information, get the PIN from the API and send all the data up to your website. Once registration is complete, the application could be a web shortcut to your site, if that's what you want, or the user could delete it.